# PHP regex replace keyword in text but not inside anchor tags

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to implement automatic hyperlink function for keywords.

The issue I am having that a keyword can be a part of other keyword. For example: potato, sweet potato. The function has to know not to hyperlink potato in sweet potato..

I am using regex and it actually works on different environments but not in my localhost and not in live version..

Working example:

```
$keywords_external = array(
  "Sweet potato" => "food/sweet-potato", 
  "Potato salads" => "food/potato-salads",
  "Potato" => "food/potato", 
);

$data = array(
  'post_content' => 'Sweet potato some text then potato then more text and then potato salads'
);

foreach($keywords_external as $key => $href) 
{
  $regex = '/<a\b(?=\s)(?:[^>=]|=\'[^\']*\'|="[^"]*"|=[^\'"\s]*)*"\s?>.*?<\/a>|('.$key.')/ims';

  $data['post_content'] = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function ($matches) {
        if (array_key_exists (1, $matches)) {
           return '<a href="https://example.com/">'. $matches[1] .'</a>';
        }
        return $matches[0];
    },
    $data['post_content']
  );
}

echo $data['post_content'];
```

Works on http://phpfiddle.org

Same example does not work in live version..

Any ideas to achieve same thing differently or why it does not might work in live version?

Thanks.

**PHP VERSIONS**
Localhost: PHP Version 7.0.12,
Live: PHP Version 7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, 
Live which works: PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: What is PHP version on local and live?

Comment: @DollyAswin Localhost: PHP Version 7.0.12, Live: PHP Version 7.0.15-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Live which works: PHP Version 5.4.45

Comment: Could you provide an example input string? I'm asking because I have a hard time understanding your regex. It seems to be looking for keywords in a hyperlink instead of turning keywords into a hyperlink. Also as a general tip: It's always best to provide an input example and what the result should be.

Comment: @icecub: no actually the pattern tries to match hyperlinks before the keyword to avoid the content already enclosed between "a" tags, that's why he tests if `$matches[1]` is set before returning the replacement string. It isn't a bad idea that should work, but it's better to do it in a single pass to avoid this test.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes, this is exactly the case

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I see. It got me confused because when I enter the regex on [https://regex101.com/r/hvklF0/2](https://regex101.com/r/hvklF0/2) it matches any hyperlink, but nothing else.

Comment: Very strange.. regex kind of works.. What can be related between PHP version (web server environment) and regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edit]: since you are dealing with multibyte characters, the code needs to be edited a little:

I don't know what is your exact problem but, this is the way I will do it (in a single pass):

```
// all keys must be lowercase
$keywords_external_path = array(
    "business analyst là gì" => "business-analyst/", 
    "tài liệu cho business analyst" => "tai-lieu-cho-business-analyst/", 
    "product manager là gì" => "product-manager-la-gi/", 
    "công việc của product manager" => "product-manager-phai-biet-dat-cau-hoi/", 
    "QA là gì" => "qc-la-gi-qa-la-gi/", 
    "QC là gì" => "qc-la-gi-qa-la-gi/", 
    "Kiểm thử phần mềm là gì" => "kiem-thu-phan-mem-ai-lam-chang-duoc/", 
    "Automation QA là gì" => "3-loi-khuyen-giup-ban-nang-cap-su-nghiep-qa/", 
    "Tester là gì" => "tester-thanh-cong/", 
    "kỹ năng của Tester giỏi" => "tester-thanh-cong/", 
    "công việc QA" => "qa-gioi/", 
    "Technical Architect là gì" => "how-to-become-ta/", 
);

//change the keys to lowercase (support multibyte characters)
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
$keywords_external_path = array_combine(
    array_map('mb_strtolower', array_keys($keywords_external_path)), 
    $keywords_external_path
);

$data = array(
  'post_content' => '"business analyst là gì" => "business-analyst/", 
            "tài liệu cho business analyst" => "tai-lieu-cho-business-analyst/", 
            "product manager là gì" => "product-manager-la-gi/", 
            "công việc của product manager" => "product-manager-phai-biet-dat-cau-hoi/", 
            "QA là gì" => "qc-la-gi-qa-la-gi/", 
            "QC là gì" => "qc-la-gi-qa-la-gi/", 
            "Kiểm thử phần mềm là gì" => "kiem-thu-phan-mem-ai-lam-chang-duoc/", 
            "Automation QA là gì" => "3-loi-khuyen-giup-ban-nang-cap-su-nghiep-qa/", 
            "Tester là gì" => "tester-thanh-cong/", 
            "kỹ năng của Tester giỏi" => "tester-thanh-cong/", 
            "công việc QA" => "qa-gioi/", 
            "Technical Architect là gì" => "how-to-become-ta/"'
);

$base = 'http://yourdomain.com/'; // only if this is useful

$keywords_external = array_map(function ($i) {
    return preg_quote($i, '~');
}, array_keys($keywords_external_path));
rsort($keywords_external);

// to quickly discard useless positions (if you have many keywords):
// you can also do the same with the second letter
$keywords_first_letter = implode('',
    array_unique(
        array_reduce($keywords_external, function ($c, $i) {
            $c[] = mb_substr($i, 0, 1); return $c;
        }, [])
    )
);

$pattern = '~'
         . '(?=['. preg_quote($keywords_first_letter, '~') . '])'
         . '(?=\b\w|(?<!\S)\W)'
         . '(?:' . implode('|', $keywords_external) . ')'
         . '(?<=\w\b|\W(?!\S))~iu';

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) use ($keywords_external_path, $base) {
    return '<a href="' . $base . $keywords_external_path[mb_strtolower($m[0])] . '">'
         . $m[0] . '</a>'; 
}, $data['post_content']);

echo $result;
```

[demo with several php versions](https://3v4l.org/H0gib)

Comment: What if I have some keys in uppercase? Thanks. I have 2 sets of keywords and very strangely some works some do not..

Comment: @mintaras: Convert them to lowercase before, otherwise `$keywords_external_path[strtolower($m[0])]` will refer to an index that doesn't exist. About the two set of keywords, you need to put them in a single array, for example: `['abcd'=>['rep' =>'folder/abcd', 'set' => 1], 'efgh'=>['rep'=>'folder/efgh', 'set'=>'2],...]` *(obviously you need to adapt the code a little with this kind of array but it isn't difficult)*

Comment: I have removed strtolower from this place.. See example with real keywords: https://3v4l.org/q1TVa  UPDATE: https://3v4l.org/Feodo

Comment: I have just put your code to a function and I am calling the function couple of times

Comment: Can it be related to special characters used in my keys? For example: key "business analyst" works, but key "business analyst là gì" does not.. (Vietnamese)

Comment: @mintaras: since you are dealing with multibyte characters, try this version: https://3v4l.org/WYCZ4

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much.

Comment: It seems that I have some special characters in my keywords too. Like: "+ (plus sign), / (slashes), # (hashtag), ? (question mark)".. How I could include those? Thanks

Comment: @mintaras: apply `preg_quote` to  `$keywords_external` using `array_map` *(see PHP manual)*. Eventually, remove the word-boundaries from the pattern if you have keywords that starts with special characters, or replace them with the appropriate lookarounds.

Comment: Works like charm! One interesting thing.. One specific keyword does not work and nest multiple anchor tags which breaks formatting.. I think it might have something to do with `$keywords_first_letters` First goes this keyword: "juicy sweet red apples" and then "sweet red" is being nested inside the first one..

Comment: @mintaras: I have no explanation for this strange result. It isn't supposed to happen since the string is parsed only once. About `$keywords_first_letters`, I don't think it causes the problem, but you should also apply `preg_quote` to it *(if a first character is one of these special characters: `-`, `^`, `]`)*. Put the shortest code to reproduce the problem on 3v4l.org, this way I will see what happens.

Comment: You said ".. parsed only once". Actually I am parsing it twice.. and this exact keyword goes in separate iteration. But because of that I run array with longer keywords first "juicy sweet red apples" goes first and it is already in anchor tag. Then I run array with "sweet red".. I run it twice because two sets of keywords has different url parameters..

Comment: @mintaras: a way to do it *(need to be improved or written as a simple function but the idea is here)*: https://3v4l.org/qgW52